# Laravel Sanctum: Machine-to-Machine

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I've previously implemented Laravel Passport for validating users of an API.

I'm currently looking to use Laravel Sanctum. This will not be for validating users but for validating machine to machine interactions (i.e. API to API).

I've read through the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

The above documentation is focussed around generating tokens for users upon logging in. This application has no users and simply needs to generate API tokens for machine to machine authentication.

How would a token be generated without users?

Comment: I guess you would need to have a `machine` table for which you are generating these tokens

Answer (score 0):

For Machine, to Machine, you have to use Laravel Passport.

Comment: you absolutely don't "have" to use Passport for that. additionally, it's even simpler to use Sanctum as you can generate all users/token via a commandline, where Passport forces you to use a http request from your other machine in order to create a token (which is totally dumb)